# Поиск профессиональной литературы

Tags: книги, javascript, php

Какие книги,сайты или что-то ещё вы могли бы посоветовать по углубленному изучению javascript и php?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: W3C вроде как не жалует этот сайт.

И не все примеры из w3schools проходят валидацию.

От некоторых - браузер вообще падает. Проверял на body onload="alert('123')", браузер точно не вспомню какой. Хотя body onload="alert('123')" вроде даже в спецификации есть...

Хотя для изучения основ - подойдет.

Comment: нужны не основы. О углубленная литература

Comment: слово "углубленному" тут ключевое)

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript: The Good Parts — Douglas Crockford](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742). Хорошая книга для начала.
[JavaScript Design Patterns — Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/). Паттерны проектирования в JS.
[PHP 5 в подлиннике — Д. Котеров, А. Костарев](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2172211/). Учился писать на PHP по ней.
[Программист-прагматик — Э. Хант, Д. Томас](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1657382/). Объясняет как надо программировать на любом языке.

Answer (score 1):

[PHPClub - клуб разработчиков PHP](http://phpclub.ru/talk/) - один из самых популярных ресурсов.

Comment: отлично, спасибо)